# Custom menu that handles content type creation

Tags: navigation, 9

I'm a Drupal 9 newbie, and right now I'm on steep side of the learning curve.
I apologize if my question is a bit messy and long. Please bear with me.

I'm on Drupal 9.4.8 with a Bootstap 5 theme.

I'm planning on making a custom dynamic menu in a department page that handles additional content ( hope that makes sense... )

I have a dynamic department page which is created via my DepartmentsController showSingle(department_id) function,
which again passes all relevant backend data to my show-single-department.html.twig, and that works perfectly.
I can access every single department page with /department/{department_id}.

Here's what I'm thinking:

- On each of my department pages, I need a menu UI which can handle additional content.(create, delete, edit, reorder etc.)
- This menu should have no more than three levels:

  - Parent department_document

    - Child department_document

      - Grandchild department_document
- For the additional content, I'll create a simple department_document content type with a title field and a body field.
- On each of my department pages, I'll have the menu on the left side, and the additional content to the right.
- The department_document content on the right side should be shown in the same order as in the menu.
- When the user clicks on a menu link, the content part scrolls down to the relevant department_document using anchor elements or JS.

I've been googling a solution for a while now, but that only made me more confused.
I found the [Inline Entity Form Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form), but it seems to only handle the document structure.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, or am I on the wrong track here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems there are some hidden requirements here.  What does " which needs to be shown one after another"?  And at the end " parent, child and grandchild department_documents"-- what is this hierarchy requirement?  It seems like everything else is pretty standard and can easily be handled.

Comment: Hi @PatrickKenny

I can see what you mean, sorry about that.
I've edited my question, so I hope I make more sense now